# Differentiate between a single finger drag and a multi finger drag on a canvas in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and i am trying to figure out how to differentiate between a single finger drag and a multi finger drag on a canvas

Comment: what `on*` callbacks are you using in [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)?

Comment: i tried to use onhorizontaldrag callback, but it does not indicate how many fingers on the screen at a given time.

Comment: use `onScale*` then

Comment: i want to be able to use onpan as well and i cant use both of them together according to the runtime error generated by flutter

Comment: you dont need `onPan*` if you use `onScale*` - you can get the same info from `onScale*` "details" parameters passed with callbacks

Comment: in onscale* how do i know if the event was pan or scale?
and also in onhorizontaldrag how can i know if the drag was with a single finger or multifinger.
thanks in advance :)